# Is there a more pythonic way of storing parameters so they can be used in a function call?

Tags: python

I'm currently writing a small script using pygame, but I don't believe this question to be related strictly to pygame.

I have a class that holds a dictionary of function parameters contained in tuples:

```
self.stim = {1:(firstParam, secondparam, thirdparam),
            2:(firstParam2, secondparam2, thirdparam2),
            3:(firstParam3, secondParam3, thirdParam3)}
```

In the same class, I have a function that issues a call to another function using these parameters:

```
def action(self, stimType):
    pygame.draw.rect(self.stim[stimType][0], self.stim[stimType][1], self.stim[stimType][2])
```

It works, but it's a bit ugly to read. I was wondering if there was a more elegant way of storing these parameters such that a function can be called using them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sure, it is called [argument list unpacking](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) (thanks Björn Pollex for the link):

```
def action(self, stimType):
    pygame.draw.rect(*self.stim[stimType])
```

And if you are not using a dict for any particular reason, then a tuple for the collection of different arguments is better suited and more peformant:

```
self.stim = (
    (firstParam, secondparam, thirdparam),
    (firstParam2, secondparam2, thirdparam2),
    (firstParam3, secondParam3, thirdParam3)
)
```

Just remember that the indexes now start at 0: `self.stim[stimType]` becomes `self.stim[stimType-1]`

Comment: Cool!  I was vaguely considering using a named tuple, but it still seemed way too verbose.  Could you please explain what the * character does in this context?  I'm not familiar with this notation.

Comment: This is called [argument-list-unpacking](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

Comment: It's the "splat" operator. Similar to in Java how you have the ellipsis operator that takes variadic arguments and passes them as an array, but like in reverse.

Comment: damn! you beat me for one second. The `*` magic is definitely the right thing to do here.

Comment: @Björn Pollex: Thanks for the link, added it to the answer ;-)

Comment: @BjörnPollex:  Very cool!  Thank you for the link! My first reflex was to say "Wow!  You can dereference pointers in python?!" =P